# Angular 6 Dashboard housing multiple apps at one place

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

I have 3 applications running in single Angular App as 3 different routes.

```
-src
  -app
     --Modules
         --App1
         --App2
         --App3
```

These three apps are completely different. However because of the current architecture these app share themes, assets, etc. Sometimes, change in app1 causes unexpected results in app2. I want to avoid that.

**What I want to achieve:**
(1) Create three different application -  app1, app2 and app3. This is easy.

(2) Create another angular app (dashboard like) where app1, app2, and app3 appear as a widgets and clicking on them will take you to corresponding application. Something similar to below:

I need help with (2)

[image]

This will be similar to [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) from Angular.io where each block is a different application and not a route.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/glxqybekpky?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts

http://plnkr.co/edit/PMkIbCWJAAlxLBYgDcTG?p=preview

**What I have done so far**

I have created a separate dashboard application which has widgets for each apps.

I have also created individual application (for app1, app2 and app3). In addition, I have created [library](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-library) for each of the app and published it. This is how app1-lib.module.ts looks like. app2-lib and app3-lib have similar structure.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { app1LibComponent } from './employee-lib.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ],
  declarations: [app1LibComponent],
  exports: [app1LibComponent]
})
export class app1LibModule { }
```

In my main Dashboard Application, **application.component.ts** looks like.

```
import {Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Applications} from './apps.model'; //Class with all app names (app1, app2, app3)

@Component({
  selector: 'app-applications',
  templateUrl: './applications.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./applications.component.css']
})
export class ApplicationsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  apps: Applications[] = [
   {id : 1,name :'app1'},
   {id : 2,name :'app2'},
   {id : 3,name :'app3'},
  ]
  }
```

applications.component.html

```
<div class="grid grid-pad">
  <a *ngFor="let app of apps" class="col-1-4"
      routerLink="/{{app.name}}">
    <div class="module hero">
      <h4>{{app.name }}</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**app-routing.module.ts** looks like below. I am extracting component from each application library and assigning it to dashboard application path.

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

    import { ApplicationsComponent } from './applications/applications.component';
    import {app1LibComponent} from 'app1Lib';
    import {app2LibComponent} from 'app2Lib'
    import {app3LibComponent} from 'app3Lib';

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'application', component: ApplicationsComponent},
    {path: 'app1', component: app1LibComponent},
    {path: 'app2', component :app2LibComponent},
    {path: 'app3', component :app3LibComponent},
   ];

    @NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
      ],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach.

I am looking for suggestions on how to create this architecture. Thanks all !

Comment: is your approach working this way? I want to know that are you able to access all the apps from your dashboard app? is your applications run on different ports? How are you managing the navigation to different app from the dashboard app? is your Dashboard a parent App?